# hover works only when entering from outside of container IE

Tags: html, css

i saw many problems with IE but none was the same as mine.
i have a gallery on my site, there are navigation arrows on each pic. i use hover to figure on which half of the picture the user hovers and to show the right arrow accordingly,
the problem is that the hover works only when i enter the mouse from outside the div that contains the arrows, when i move form one arrow to another it dosent work. 
here the code:

```
<div class="lb-container">
<img class="lb-image" src="http://suburbanfinance.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/streetinfo.jpg?973b8a" style="display: block; width: 724px; height: 543px;">
<div class="lb-nav" style="display: block;">
<a class="lb-prev" href="" style="display: block;"></a>
<a class="lb-next" href="" style="display: block;"></a>
</div>
<div class="lb-loader" style="display: none;"><a class="lb-cancel">
</a></div></div>
```

and the css:

```
.lb-next:hover {
  background: url(../images/next.png) right 48% no-repeat;
}
.lb-prev:hover {
  background: url(../images/prev.png) left 48% no-repeat;
}
```

ideas?

Comment: Could be related to the fact that old IE doesn't support a:hover unless it contains a href. Use `href="#"` and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: unforunatlly it didnt help my friend... the hover works when coming from outside but doesnt work from whithin.... very wierd

Comment: could be positioning and something is laying over the <a>

Comment: no but for some reason the place where it gets the hover is only over the IMG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason elements without a background are transparent to mouse events in IE. Try setting an *almost* transparent background:

```
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.001);
```

I'm guessing at your mark-up but I've mocked this up via [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QEpra/1/) and it worked for me.